# how to drop user defined database in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am trying to drop a user-defined database, like so:

```
create database demo;
drop database demo;
```

But I get the error

> Cannot drop the database 'demo',
>   because it does not exist or you do
>   not have permission.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code so my guess would be that you don't have permissions to delete the database.

Answer (score 1):

One way to sort this out might be to run

```
SELECT name FROM sys.databases
```

to see if the database does exist.

Some helpful tips from [MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178613.aspx)

- To use `DROP DATABASE`, the database
  context of the connection cannot be
  the same as the database to be
  dropped. You could change your
  context to, for example `USE master`
  before running `DROP`
- To execute `DROP DATABASE`, at a
  minimum, a user must have `CONTROL`
  permission on the database.

You might find some other useful information there that applies to your specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
create database demo;
drop database demo;
```

In the above code, if the database is deleted and again tried to delete the database which does not exists will give you the error as you mentioned